# base_footprint tf does not show up under odom in tf-tree graph

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: Do transforms show up if they are not associated with links in a urdf? If not then this is not a real question.

base_footprint published by robot_pose_ekf shows in the rviz tf tree under odom node but does not show in the tf-tree graph. Why would this be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110446/base_footprint-tf-does-not-show-up-under-odom-in-tf-tree-graph/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, transforms can come from anywhere, not only the URDF. AFAIK the tf tools and rviz do not even use the URDF (for displaying tf information).

There might be problems if the tf tree is not connected, i.e. if there is more than one tree.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0